# Outlook 2003 Crashes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, crash, debug, microsoft-outlook-2003

Outlook 2003 just started crashing.  There's not much to go on.  I get a window that says "Microsoft Office Outlook has stopped working".

I've archived all but 1 month of emails.
I turned off the reading pane.
I renamed the OST file and let outlook rebuild it.
I removed the archive folders.
I turned off all the rules.

What can I do to track down the cause of the crash?

Comment: Since you already had outlook rebuild the OST once, you might want to try simply reinstalling the program.

Comment: I did do a repair - didn't help.  I also did an uninstall / reinstall.  Maybe I'll do that again but this time renaming the OST so everything is fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed my problem:

Uninstall Outlook.
Remove the email profile (Control Panel --> Mail).
Install Outlook.
Setup the Email Account.

The script that my IT gave me to auto create my email account did not work.  My guess is that I have something corrupt in my registry.

I probably could have fixed this by just removing and recreating my mail profile.